# MS Office on the App Store: will it work with an existing 365 subscription?

Tags: mac, ms-office, office-365

Microsoft's Office apps have recently become available on the App Store. Can I use my existing Office 365 for Business subscription with these apps?

Comment: Did you find anything on microsoft.com about it?

Comment: First place I looked but that place is a mess. Also my experience with their support staff is bad. You’ll have to set an auto response “NO BUT I HAVE A MAC!” to every mail you get from them.

Comment: There's no reason to swap to the MAS copies of the applications, is there?

Comment: @MarcWilson I prefer getting my applications from the MAS as it makes transition smoother when I'm switching to a new computer, or when I'm reinstalling everything after a clean install of the OS.